# Создание модульного теста функции factorize в Python. Сделал. Дает ошибку

Tags: python, тестирование

Создание модульного теста функции factorize. 
Дана функция factorize(x) со следующим контрактом:

```
def factorize(x):
""" Factorize positive integer and return its factors.
    :type x: int,>=0
    :rtype: tuple[N],N>0
"""
pass
```

Написать комплект тестов:

```
test_wrong_types_raise_exception
test_negative
test_zero_and_one_cases
test_simple_numbers
test_two_simple_multipliers
test_many_multipliers
```

Проверить в них соответственно:

Что типы float и str (значения 'string', 1.5) вызывают исключение TypeError.
Что для отрицательных чисел -1, -10 и -100 вызывается исключение ValueError.
Что для числа 0 возвращается кортеж (0,), а для числа 1 кортеж (1,)
Что для простых чисел 3, 13, 29 возвращается кортеж, содержащий одно данное число.
Что для чисел 6, 26, 121 возвращаются соответственно кортежи (2, 3), (2, 13) и (11, 11).
Что для чисел 1001 и 9699690 возвращаются соответственно кортежи (7, 11, 13) и (2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19).
При этом несколько различных проверок в рамках одного теста должны быть обработаны как подслучаи с указанием x: subTest(x=...).

ВАЖНО! Название переменной в тестовом случае должно быть именно "x". Все входные данные должны быть такими, как указано в условии. В задании необходимо реализовать ТОЛЬКО класс TestFactorize, кроме этого реализовывать ничего не нужно. Импортировать unittest и вызывать unittest.main() в решении также не нужно.

Написал:

```
import unittest
def factorize(x):
    """ Factorize integer positive and return its factors.
        :type x: int,>=0
        :rtype: tuple[N],N>0
    """
    pass

class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_wrong_types_raise_exception(self):
      for x in ('string', 1.5):
        with self.subTest(x=x):
          self.assertRaises(TypeError, factorize, x)

    def test_negative(self):
      for x in (-1, -10, -100):
        with self.subTest(x=x):
          self.assertRaises(ValueError, factorize, x)

    def test_zero_and_one_cases(self):
      for x in (0, 1):
        with self.subTest(x=x):
          self.assertEqual(factorize(x), (x,))

    def test_simple_numbers(self):
      for x in (3, 13, 29):
        with self.subTest(x=x):
          self.assertEqual(factorize(x), (x,))

    def test_two_simple_multipliers(self):
      for x, answer in ((6, (2,3)), (26, (2,13)), (121, (11,11))):
        with self.subTest(x=x):
          self.assertEqual(factorize(x), answer)

    def test_many_multipliers(self):
      for x, answer in ((1001, (7, 11, 13)), (9699690,  (2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19))):
        with self.subTest(x=x):
          self.assertEqual(factorize(x), answer)
if __name__ != "__main__":      
  unittest.main()
```

> Дает ошибку! 
>   RuntimeErrorElement(RuntimeError,Error in grading script. See raw output log for details.)
>   Помогите исправить ошибку. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Текст "See raw output log for details" как бэ намекает...

Comment: Я только учусь..

Answer (score 1):

Плохо, что вы не написали, как вы запускаете этот код и какая у вас версия питона.

Я перепробовал все варианты, которые мне пришли в голову, но именно такой ошибки, как у вас, получить не смог.

Но, как минимум, если вы запускаете этот код напрямую, а не импортируете где-то в другом месте, то вот в этой строчке

```
if __name__ != "__main__":
```

Нужно заменить `!=` на `==`